# Unity Android build : Google Play services stops when mirroring via Chromecast

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video-streaming, chromecast

I made an Android App on Unity.
It includes a few videos, 
When mirroring a device (Galaxy tab A 2018) on a Chromecast, it first works but crashes when playing videos. Error : Google Play Services has stopped.

I tried pretty much everyting including clearing and updating Play services and Android version.

On some other devices (phones mostly) it works flawlessly.

First time working with Chromecast and cant seem to find similar error by developpers.

Edit : The difference in Logcat when I'm with Chromecast is this line :

W/Unity: AndroidVideoMedia: Error -10000 while configuring codec.

(The video format is mp4)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you share some error logs and steps to replicate the issue so the community will have an insight of the problem?

Comment: This is the Logcat error : W/Unity: AndroidVideoMedia: Error -10000 while configuring codec.